# How far should the well for a temperature gauge extend into a 3/4" pipe?

Tags: plumbing, copper, gauge

I have a 1/2" well insert for a temperature gauge. I'm connecting it to a 3/4" pipe thought a tee fitting. I've noticed that when it's inserted the well obstructs quite a bit of the inside of the fitting. Not just on the sides but between the bottom of the well and the wall of the pipe.

My concern is that the well will obstruct the flow of water to a significant degree.

What kind of clearance should exist when using an insert type temperature gage in a 3/4" pipe?

Comment: Considering that copper and brass are good thermal conductors is it really a concern? Presumably all parts will be very close to water temp.

Comment: To that point, I'de even thought about just using an infrared thermometer, because of the thermal conductivity of copper and specific heat of water. However having gauges in place seemed more reliable. My real concern is that the well will obstruct the flow of water to a non insignificant degree.

Comment: I see. Let's get rid of that double negative and just say "significant". :)

Comment: I guess the purpose of the temp gauge would be important if it is for a process that has critical temp control the sensor in the stream would be important. If it’s for automatic faucet temp control on copper pipe I have attached the thermocouple you the pipe and it worked without leaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it depends on what you consider significant, a half inch pipe is pretty small and depending on the rate of flow I imagine it could be an issue.

But you can have your cake and eat it too - you can install a gauge without the well.  There are external sensors made to attach to the exterior of the pipe like this thermistor

[image: Pipe Thermistor]

This one is $12 and much less work to install.